# Barest minimum code to present a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frameworks, uikit

What's the absolute bare minimum code to create a project that creates a UIView and shows it on the screen of an iOS device?

*Without Storyboards, templates or any other contrivance. Just the barest presentation of a UIView.*

I appreciate the templates are there to make things "easier", but for the sake of comprehending how everything works together, I'd like to try to conceive the frameworks and their relationships with the OS in the barest, truly code based form.

i.e. without Storyboards and all their processes. Just purely in code.

I've tried using google to find something with someone discussing iOS in an holistic manner, so as to view Views with clarity... but it's all about "ease" rather than understanding, so far as I can see.

With Swift.

// All puns were non-intential byproducts of irritation.

EDIT:::

How do I even start a new Project without a View Controller, Storyboard etc? There seems to be only storyboard based templates, and no way to start a "blank" project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

barest minimum would be this, just place this in your app delegate, delete the other .swift files, and this should be the barest you need:

```
  import UIKit

  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootViewController: UINavigationController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
     }
   }
```

this requires Zero storyboards, BUT if you want add a VIEW to all of this and have control over that uiview, then do this:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootViewController: UINavigationController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        var firstVC = UIViewController()
        var firstVCView = UIView()
        firstVCView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        firstVC.view = firstVCView

        rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)    self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

i can show you from the start, ill start a brand new project and strip it:

here's how:

1. select sinlge view application project
2. go into info.plist file, delete these two entries:

[image]

[image]

3. Then, delete the storyboard, and the nib.
4. Keep the "ViewController.swift" file
5. place this in your AppDelegate.swift:

   ```
   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow?
       var rootViewController: UINavigationController?

       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
           self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
           rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
           self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
           self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
6. then, do this, click no the button "use asset catalog"

[image]

7. the click on the pop up box that you want to use an asset catalog, then make sure this field is blank, where it says "launch screen file"
8. compile and run your project

[image]

Comment: I'm trying this out now... and am a moron.

Comment: Xcode tells me this: UIViewController.new())  should be UIViewController())

Comment: xcode isnt' telling this to me, I've tested both and I'm using THE most up to date version of xcode, NOT the new beta

Comment: Well, I'm confused. So there's that ;) And I'm on the beta. Sorry.

Comment: UIWindow inherits from UIView, so you don't even need the UINavigationController to get a view onscreen. However, you will get a warning on the console that applications are expected to have a root view controller.

Comment: In the second example, can you explain what that if let window = window { etc } is doing?

Comment: yeah, dmdm, I know, but doing what you say to do is worthelss since you need a navigationcontroller so making comments like you made is going to confuse the hell out of new people, you might want to rethink telling people to start an app without a navigationcontroller

Comment: @Confused so you are tyring to start using Xcode with a Beta Xcode? That's not a very good idea. If you don't first know how to use the full release version then you should stick to the most up to date version that is the RELEASE version, not the beta version, you are making this very hard on yourself and I can see that it looks like you are just getting started with Xcode or IOS or both

Comment: No, it's going to be too confusing, so let me delete this, one sec

Comment: I'm trying to reset my understanding of how it all goes together. I know some of the frameworks, but how to start, holistically, I have no idea about. And I want that DEEP view of how everything comes together, from the beginning. I jumped this stage. And it was a massive mistake. I'm suffering for not having a proper understanding of the intricacies. Am very grateful you understand (seemingly innately) the point of my question. Downloading actual release Xcode now...

Comment: good, well, if you want to dive deep, @Confused, then the easiest way to do this is to make sure that first off, you DON'T need the If/then statement I had in my code, and then you need to understand this: 1. every viewController should have control over a view, and this view can be a compound view with up to an infinite amount of views incuding nearly all items listed in UIKit. If you want your view contorllers to navigable, then your view controllers need to be inside a UINavigationController. The View of your UIViewControllers can be loaded through the "loadView" method in the ViewControlle

Comment: you can then set the view for the UIViewController, then, in your viewDidLoad, you implement additional set up that the UIView you set in your loadView didn't do ... that is things like setting up button listeners, setting delegates, etc. Then in your viewWillAppear method, you set up additional UIEffects that you didn't set up in your ViewDidLoad. You do things in ViewWillAppear that you want the ViewController to ALWAYS have even when the back button is pressed to arrive at said viewController

Comment: This is how you set up everything programmatically, and this a very very very very high level set up, there's a lot of detail that I don't have time to explain, but the idea is this: 1. you subclass a UIView, this is a completely separate .swift file, you implement it's super class methods and intiliazers, you custom the view. 2. you set the view of the ViewController to this new subclass by typecasting the UIViewController's view property, 3. you call loadView method in the controller, 4. You call viewDidLoad, 5, then viewWillAppear, 6. then ViewDidAppear,  ...etc. etc.

Comment: From this basic understanding of the depths of iOS, I plan to head to Scene Kit and Sprite Kit, and leave the whole "App Making" thing behind. But I do, as you correctly point out, need to have an understanding of how to navigate between Views. That's something I overlooked, also. But clearly I should definitely get a good grasp on as as it likely informs the manner, nature and purpose of Views and View controllers. Or something like that. I'm flummoxed by the complexity of just a base project, at this point.

Comment: To do scenekit stuff, you definitely should know how to programmatically create views, how to manipulate layers, how to take advantage of UINavigationController and UIViewController subclassing, how to subclass in general, programmatically, how to typecast a viewController's view, memory management fundamentals with core animation and Scenekit/GPU processs memory management (little things like iterating through ALL views in an app and setting the layer opacity to TRUE for everything), you should know WHY doing stuff like setting layers to opaque will help performance. ..

Comment: You should understand things like how to clone nodes so as to not overload the GPU with useless geometry that could have been a reference geomentry clone, you should know how to work with nodes in scene subclasses, when you should implement your own glsl shaders, when shoudl you override some of the redering stuff and more. But I'd suggest, as you've admitted, to first get the heirarchical stuff out of the way so you are comforatable with manipulating views to a point where you can sort of do anything you want with UIKit programmatically.

Comment: I'll post a starter project here later with autolayout constratins, typecasting a view controller subclassing uiviews etc in swift to show you, this isn't available in too many places since people default to storyboards now.

Comment: Yes, the default to storyboards is EVERYWHERE. I simply wanted to deeply understand what was going on, not take any "shortcuts", and to start thinking in terms of the actual structure. Unfortunately I've spent a lot of time as a designer working with developers, wherein they provide me access to variables and other things for to adjust, but when it comes to actually grokking the whole, I'm astonishingly clueless. 3 years of using Xcode and I'm utterly hopeless and helpless without a programmer next to me. Retarded, I'm sure.

Comment: Well, you can learn the programmatic way, but there's very very little information out there, and unless you find someone willing to share (myself for instance, I'll share as much as I can before I need to get to work on a few apps I have in the pipeline) then there's very little help to get to the level of never needing to use a nib or storyboard. I got lucky, my first project, I took over a project with 100k lines of code, all programmatic from two University professors, using C, C++, and Objective-C, so I was forced to learn this. It was my job to do what they couldn't and I did.

Comment: give me like 30 minutes to an hour, I'll post some swift start project stuff with full on programmatic handling, this will be more useful than you realize, but you'll have to go through this to understand what's going on, but if you have questions, there's some very smart people here on SO that answer IOS questions and they know how to do things programmatically.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! btw I'd love to "assist" your deeper answer with 3D drawings of the hierarchy of elements that make up this initial project, with an iPhone/iPad in the background and drawings of each element in a hierarchical schematic so that those that follow can benefit instantly from a visual guide to what is where, and communicates in what manner. Is there a way we can pass email addresses with some kind of confidentiality?

Comment: yeah, do this, i'll open a chat here, the chat thing you see in this comment stuff, and just post there for now, I'll thingk of a way to do the email thing later, but there's going to be a ton of info you'll see just today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88269/discussion-between-larcerax-and-confused).

Answer (score 0):

A completely empty application with an app delegate, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` this will present a view:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
```

there is a view in `UIViewController`